# IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal server error . Error Code-0x80070003

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-10, .net-4.8, windows-server-2019

I have an existing ASP.NET webforms application written in VB.NET and running on .NET 4.8 which is perfectly running on the production server since 2022. At that time prod server was Windows Server 2016.

Recently, I enhanced the application and deployed to the Dev server (Windows Server 2016) and Staging server (Windows Server 2019) for testing. Everything is working fine.

Finally, the application deployed to the prod server with new code and modified prod config file. Last year, the prod server was upgraded from 2016 to 2019. When I ran the application from prod I am now getting a http 500 error.

As per the deployment teams statement there is a correct permission on the site folder because it is existing application not new application.

Detailed error info:

> HTTP Error 500.19 -Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid
>
> Module : IIS Web Core
> Notification: BeginRequest
>
> Error Code : 0x80070003
> Config error : Cannot read configuration file
> Config file : \?<file path>\web.config
> Request Url : https://localhost:443/prj/menu.aspx
> Physical path : \menu.aspx
> IIS 10.0

I could not find the root cause. I searched in google but did not find solution. I am totally stuck.

Any kind of hints or idea is more appreciated.

Comment: golly, not much to go on here? The error suggests an issue with a config file. Hence, I would open the web.config file that exists in the folder prj if one exists. Remember, it is common to have multiple web.config files, one in each folder, since that tends to be how security is setup for such sites. However, hard to tell. Does the site build and run when you build + run inside of VS on your local developer box? Is this a "web site", or is this a "web site application"?

Comment: Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal. It is an existing VB asp.net web form application. There is a web config file in the folder. In my development machine, application is successfully built and ran to the VS 2019 after my enhancement. Also deployed to Dev and Stg servers for testing. Everything works fine. I requested to the deploy team to get the original prod web.config file and updated and replaced to the dev and stg server application folder and ran the application successfully.

Comment: You also mentioned "The error suggests and issue with a config file". What kind of issues? Is it security issue?  How can I diagnose this? I googled it but did find any clue or hints. It is hard to reproduce the scenario to Dev or Stg servers because it is running successfully to these servers. It only fails on Prod server.

Comment: It is an external website.

Comment: ok, it builds local, does it run local on dev box? And you used publish to create the final site as "release" mode for publish, right? Not clear how you moved or updated this site before a deploy. So, does a publish using "release mode" work? Don't think this is security issue but release.config may well have settings for a security certificate to allow https.  Is app pool and settings via IIS on the new server setup and running?

Comment: Application locally runs successfully. Final code is built and released using Azure CI/CD pipeline and deployed in DEV, STG and Prod boxes. DEV and STG are successfully running but failed in Prod box. Yes hosted in Prod IIS  using app pool with settings.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500.19 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks @samwu. I will tell to deployment team to enable failed request tracing to get detailed log.

Comment: Since `0x80070003` indicates the path does not exist, you should ask your deployment team to troubleshoot further (typically with a tool like Process Monitor to see what is missing and w3wp.exe wants to access).

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li. I will tell my deployment time to use Process Monitor tool.

Comment: You can also try installing url rewrite to see if that solves the problem, besides,  check the app pool and see what user it is configured to run as.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. Operation teams made mistake.